# LEGO Modulars Massive Inflation?

Tags: shopping, modular-buildings

What caused retired LEGO Modular sets to spike in value so much?

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At certain times of the year (particularly at the start of the new year) LEGO release new sets and at the same time remove older sets from their inventory.

Also, in November and December in the run up to Christmas LEGO investors may take advantage of the increased demand by raising prices. Parents buying presents for their children would perhaps bid higher than usual as they are keen to get the right present and in time for Christmas.

Comment: I am talking about how the amount they were sold for in stores or on shop at home, is half or less of how much they sell for. This js year round.

Comment: This seems to be fairly normal, these sets are very popular and the same price hike after retirement comes with other themes particularly Star Wars sets. Large sets that are LEGO store exclusives or limited run in particular.

Comment: I guess the demand for them isn't too high while in production, but they don't lose demand after retiring driving the price up due to low supply?

Comment: The demand for most modular sets are fairly consistent, perhaps more so after retirement. People are also genuinely willing to pay this price,
I was able to sell the first set I invest in (10185 Green Grocer) for 7.5x the RRP which isn't only about half of what the original Cafe Corner can be sold at.

Comment: The whole Modular Building idea is brilliant. So far, I could resist because I don't have the space to build a LEGO city. It seems that the MOC culture around the Modular line is still growing. And growth is always a good reason to invest.